# Fortran Function Redeclaring Array

Tags: arrays, fortran

So I have this code for a Fortran function and I am curious what is happening to the parameter X?

```
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION PBOIL(NGamma,T,X)
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION(A-H,O-Z)
DIMENSION X(NGamma),GAMMA(NGamma)
```

Is X an array when it's passed in? Is the X that is declared in the 3rd line different than the parameter X?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I've mostly just been reading about functions online. https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_90/08_subprograms.html
But it's difficult to understand how you defing the type of the arguements.

Comment: So doing more research it seems like the arguement type is defined in line 3.

Comment: worth a note the local variable `gamma` is declared  automatically to be length `NGamma` (assuming fortran 90+).  `X` on the other hand must already be declared of sufficient length in the calling routine.

Answer (score 0):

The first line defines the function PBOIL as having three arguments.

The second line says that variables (including arguments) whose names start with the letters A-H and O-Z are to be declared DOUBLE PRECISION (as opposed to single precision) floating point, by default.

The third line says that parameter X and local variable GAMMA are arrays, of length NGamma.

Pretty much any curent-gen FORTRAN textbook should explain the above.

I have not played with any "modern" FORTRAN compiler.  The last time I seriously touched FORTRAN was in the mid-1980s.  Based on my experience THEN, I'd be very uncomfortable about trying to declare a dynamically-sized local array in FORTRAN.  I don't see why a MODERN compiler couldn't do it, given that just about every machine these days has a decent run-time stack, but the machines I was using then didn't do that.  (The CDC 6600, the machine on which I first learned FORTRAN, did *NOT* have a stack, and I'm pretty sure variably-dimensioned local arrays were NOT allowed by its FORTRAN compilers.)

Comment: I would say quite the opposite, the current-gen Fortran textbooks will skip this and leave it to some section about obsolete features. At least My Fortran 95/2003 Explained (more than 10 years old!) is like that.

Comment: As I said, it has been a long time since I last did FORTRAN.  At that time, it was FORTRAN 77 on a Harris supermini with a 24-bit word.  I don't miss it.  (OK, I did look at the STARTRK source code more recently than that, but that was CDC 6600 FORTRAN IV, and I have extensive experience both with CDC 6600 FORTRAN *and* with the STARTRK code.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

- Is X an array when it's passed in?

Yes.  It is a `DOUBLE PRECISION` array having one dimension with the extent `NGamma`.

- Is the X that is declared in the 3rd line different than the parameter X?

First, a word of terminology:  In Fortran, X is a dummy argument (that gets associated with the actual argument of the caller).  In Fortran, a `PARAMETER` is quite a different beast: `PARAMETER`s are named constants in Fortran.

So yes, the X that is a dummy argument is the same as in the `DIMENSION` statement.  It gets its type from the `IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION` statement.

Modern ideomatic Fortran would have the declaration as something like

```
  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(NGamma), INTENT(IN) :: X
```

which would make clear to the reader that this is an array dummy argument
which is not permitted to be changed by the function.

The `GAMMA` is declared as an array of the same shape as `X`. This used to be invalid FORTRAN 77 (but accepted as an extension by many compilers), but is perfectly fine  for Fortran 90 or later.